# How to stop your source IP address being seen by a site while using proxies?

Tags: python-requests, proxy, proxies, httpx

I'm trying to scrape some data off a site using proxies, I won't put any code here since it is a bit long and maybe not important for the question. I can just list these facts:

- The code I have does work at times, meaning it should be good
- After a couple dozen requests, the script gets blocked (**even with rotating proxies!**)
- Now the interesting part: after getting blocked with one proxy provider, if I immediately switch to the next one, that one is blocked too!
- I have tried with `requests.session()` and `httpx.Client()`, and both are failing in the same way.

So I think the only conclusion here is that my IP is somehow getting leaked by these proxies and shown to the site, triggering a block from it. Proxies in question are Brightdata Datacenter (cheap ones) and Residential proxies from proxy-cheap.com which should be a bit better.

Is there a way to prevent my IP from being sent over with proxies? I don't really think there is a different option, how else could they block rotating proxies from different providers, after letting them work initially for a while.

And by the way, I'm sure it's not some mistake by me, session is created like this
 `session = httpx.Client(proxies={"http://":proxy_url, "https://":proxy_url})`
 So that every request uses the same proxy.

Comment: `httpx.Client` seems to work in a [generally equivalent](https://www.python-httpx.org/compatibility/#client-instances) way as `requests.Session`. According to [`requests` advanced usage guide](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) a `Session` object *persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance*. AFAIU a server could identify a client by their cookies I think. If so, then you could try disabling support of cookies in the `Session`, or creating a new `Session` instance before you change proxy (in case server requires cookies)...

Comment: But I am new to web programming so don't take my words for granted.

Comment: Yes, they are very similar, that's why I tried with both since the code was just about the same. I haven't tried with urllib yet since that would take more modification.

Comment: I actually want to keep cookies, since the script is supposed to open a link, solve a captcha and then get data. I have a scraping thread, so each thread works with a separate session. And like I said, it works for a short while but then it just gets blocked. Maybe I should try better proxies like the answer below suggests, maybe I would have more luck.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easy solution would be buying an elite proxy, since some proxy will tell the server that request is made by a proxy.

Comment: Best I can try is probably Brightdata Residential, will see how that goes.

Comment: I tried Brightdata ISP proxies and it's the same issue with them too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).